# Angular - Interpolation does not show current list items

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a very small application in which there are two buttons. One button adds 1 to a list, the other one adds -1. Also, I am displaying the sum of the list.

Now I have one problem. I have a interpolation of the list and the newly added values are not displayed at all, but instead only the default ones which are initialized (see controller).

Here is my template:

```
<p>Items: {{ list }}</p> <!--This is not updating-->
<p>Sum: {{ getSumOfList() }}</p>
<button (click)="addItem(1)">Add 1</button>
<button (click)="addItem(-1)">Add -1</button>
```

The corresponding controller class looks like this:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  list: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getSumOfList() {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i in this.list) { total += this.list[i]; }
    return total;
  }

  addItem(item: number) {
    this.list.push(item);
    console.log(this.list);
  }
}
```

How can I display all items of the list with the interpolation syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Use immutable syntax like this

```
this.list = [...this.list, item];
```

- You can always create a new reference to the array to allow trigger the OnChanges mechanism  (change detection) [See more](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html)
- OnChanges Lifecycle Hook will trigger only when input property's instance changes, so you must have a new reference to activate change detection.

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dsfam5)

Comment: Could you explain why I have to do this, since the console log displays all current values?

Comment: @m.aslan Just to complete this answer. If you don't want to face performance issues never, never, again: **never** call functions in template. Store the total in a variable (you can easily achieve this by using `reduce`), or create a pipe. Also, don't iterate array using `for..in` :)